# Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest error heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, heroku

I have a rails app which has search system which depends on elasticsearch, i have pushed it on heroku using the bonsai addon, but whenever i try to search something on my app it give me this error in the log.

```
2017-07-16T04:04:44.083489+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
2017-07-16T04:04:44.084229+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/search_controller.rb:7:in `show'
2017-07-16T04:04:44.084222+00:00 app[web.1]: Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest ([400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filtered]","line":1,"col":22},"status":400}):
```

**My Elasticsearch Controller**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  before_action :beautify_url
  layout "simple"

  def show
    @post_records = Post.search(query_term).paginate(page: params[:page]).records
    @posts = @post_records.to_a.select { |post| post.published? }
    @users = User.search(query_term).records.to_a
    @tags = Tag.search(query_term).records
  end

  def users
    @users = User.search(query_term).records.to_a
  end

  private

    def beautify_url
      if params[:search].present?
        case params[:action]
        when "show"
          redirect_to search_url(q: params[:search][:q])
        when "users"
          redirect_to search_users_url(q: params[:search][:q])
        end
      end
    end

    def query_term
      params[:q] || ''
    end
end
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Bonsai support here. Bonsai clusters are currently being provisioned on Elasticsearch 5.x, and as of Elasticsearch 5.0, the `filtered` query has been removed. Attempting to use a `filtered` query in 5.x results in that error message you're seeing.

From what you've shared, I would say the most likely issue is that the client is using a deprecated version of the Query DSL. That would suggest an incompatible gem version.

You can check what version your Elasticsearch gems are by running this from a command line:

`bundle show | grep elasticsearch`

If they are not 5.x.x, update them in your Gemfile:

```
gem "elasticsearch", "~> 5"
gem "elasticsearch-rails", "~> 5"
```

And run `bundle update elasticsearch elasticsearch-rails`. Push the change to Heroku and try your search again.

If that doesn't help, shoot an email to support@bonsai.io and we'll help you sort it out.

Comment: i have updated my gemfile @Rob Sears, but the problem remains the same